# Google Analytics Referral - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics

I am using ruby, and attempting to get referrals from google analytics api. Here is what I have set up:

```
sa_referral = client.execute(:api_method => analytics.data.ga.get, :parameters => {
'ids' => "ga:" + saprofileID,
'dimensions' => "ga:fullreferrer",
'metrics' => "ga:users",
'sort' => "-ga:users",
'filters' => "ga:source!=(direct);",
'start-date' => startDate,
'end-date' => endDate,
})

sa_referral_data = sa_referral do |row|

row = {
  :referral => row['0'],
  :members => row['1'], 


}
      end

send_event('sa_top_referrals', current: sa_referral_data)
```

This returns no data when called in the widget using sa_top_referrals. Below is the data the API is returning.

```
    "columnHeaders": [
  {
   "name": "ga:fullreferrer",
   "columnType": "DIMENSION",
   "dataType": "STRING"
  },
  {
   "name": "ga:users",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  }
 ],
 "totalsForAllResults": {
  "ga:users": "35638"
 },
 "rows": [
  [
   "m.facebook.com/",
   "1009"
  ],
  [
   "baidu",
   "912"
  ],
  [
   "usasexguide.info/forum/showthread.php",
   "613"
  ],
```

Ideally the information I am looking to pull down is the URL ex: m.facebook.com/ and the user count or "613". Those are the two items I am looking to pull. My question is how do I know what row those are equal to. Above i'm sending it using: `:referral => row['0'],` I'd assume the issue is that its not actually row 0, is there a way I can confirm this?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Are you looking to get the user count for `"m.facebook.com/"`? Or list all the referrals?

Comment: I am looking to get both. 

where it says 
row = {
  :referral => row['0'],
  :members => row['1'], 
}
Referral should = the link "m.facebook.com/"
members should = the user count "613" 

I hope that clears things up

Comment: "I am looking to get both."? Do you want the data from the first row?

Comment: I would like the data from every row. 
I need the link:"m.facebook.com/", and count "1009" from every row that the api returns. So basically everything after the "rows": [

Comment: OK, now I got it. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
sa_referral_data = sa_referral['rows'] do |row|
  rows.map{|r| { referrals:r[0], members:r[1] }}
end
```

Comment: Question, I implemented this as suggested and reading the answer seems that this is correct. However when I put it in it's throwing an error, please see below.

sa_referral['rows'] do |row|
  rows.map{|r| { referrals:r[0], members:r[1] }}
end

This is what I used, and here is the error: 
`require': /var/www/sites/analytics.rb:74: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
sa_referral['rows'] do |row|
                      ^
Any Idea what is causing this error?

Comment: Line 74 in the code is this portion of it: 
sa_referral['rows'] do |row|

Comment: You are missing an `end`.

Comment: The issue doesn't appear to be with the variable. I believe it has to do with the sa_referral['rows'] section. I just updated it to your latest suggestion and here is the error I am getting. 

`require': /var/www/sites/analytics.rb:74: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
sa_referral_data = sa_referral['rows'] do |row|
                                         ^

Comment: After making a few more adjustment it would appear that the variable ['rows'] does not exist which is making it error out. 

When I change this to sa_referral.data.rows do |row| there are no error messages out putted, however there is also no data output. When I change it back to sa_referral['rows'] do |row| I get syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError) sa_referral_data = sa_referral['rows'] do |row| ^

Is there a way I can troubleshoot the variable and see why that one breaks it?

Comment: The result of 'puts sa_referral' is: 

#<Google::APIClient::Result:0x007ffe70f8c548>

#<Google::APIClient::Result:0x00000003073570>

#<Google::APIClient::Result:0x00000002c6e4e8>